# Do the three X-mansions in the X-Men franchise count as a continuity error?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe

The first *X-Men* movie has a different mansion than the one used in *X2* and *The Last Stand*. *First Class* and *Days of Future Past* use a building different to both used in the original trilogy. They are all obviously different.

Is this a continuity problem??

Comment: It's certainly technically a continuity issue, but is it a *problem*? What problem would it cause?

Comment: I just don't understand why it's not seen as a big continuity issue. If you think about, it's worse than professor x coming back. At least there can be an explanation for that

Comment: Because it doesn't cause any actual issue. Aesthestics aside, what actual issue does it cause?

Comment: I'd personally be more concerned with continuity problems like the fact that Jubilee is a teenager and a student in both the 80's and the early 2000's, or that Angel and Psylocke don't age in those decades - and have completely different backstories. *Those* are continuity errors.

Comment: I see your point. What problems do the other continuity errors create??

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the fact that Rogue completely vanished in the most recent film. And noone in-universe even mentioned it. You'd think they'd all be "where the hell is rogue?" but no.

Comment: @Richard In the final cut of *DoFP*, it's easy to assume she's dead. Not the intended case, of course, as we'll see with *The Rogue Cut* of the movie.

Comment: The thing is, the x mansion is such a huge part of the xmen franchise. Changing it is like recasting so many times, and people are frustrated by the three kitty prides

Comment: It's visully inconsistent. Maybe I'm the only one bothered by it

Comment: I'm not saying no one cares, but this is honestly the first time I've ever seen/anyone care about the "recasting" of the mansion other than to note that a different building was used.

Comment: Nah I still love the x men films

Comment: I just wanted to see people's opinions on it. Its strange, it's like the only continuity error that slightly bothers me because the others can be saved by new films and stories

Comment: So is suppose if it causes any issue, it would be a visual inconsistency

Comment: “If you think about, it's worse than professor x coming back. At least there can be an explanation for that.” Absolutely! There’s no way that new buildings can just be... built.

Comment: @phantom42: “In the final cut of DoFP, it's easy to assume she's dead.” Really? We do see her right at the end, no?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite after the timeline update, yes - but she's absent from the sentinel-filled future scenes.

Comment: Does recasting war machine in iron man 2 count as a continuity error? No. Neither does this. A filming gaff between scenes might be, but background aesthetic between films doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. **Within the comics - specifically the 616 continuity - the mansion located at 1407 Graymalkin Lane, Salem Center, NY has been destroyed and rebuilt numerous times.**

[image]

On many occasions, the mansion that houses the X-Men's famous [**School for Gifted Youngsters**](http://marvel.wikia.com/Xavier's_School_for_Gifted_Youngsters) has been entirely demolished, often at the hands of some villain or destructive event. In each case, the mansion is rebuilt. In most cases, the opportunity is taken to expand the mansion itself, thus making room for additional students and facilities.

It's important to note that both the interior and exteriors of the mansion have varied quite a bit over the years. With some rebuilds, great care was taken to replicate the previous appearance, while with other rebuilds the layout and/or style of the mansion was changed drastically. On at least three occasions, the entire mansion was rebuilt but you'd only know it once entering the lower levels - the mansion proper was identical to the previous building.

**Note:** At one point in continuity, the school was relocated to [a different mansion](http://marvel.wikia.com/Massachusetts_Academy) in Snow Valley, Massachusetts. The information in this answer pertains to the Xavier family home, in which Professor X originally started his X-Men team.

Comment: That's cool to know, thanks. Let's say it was destryoyed after the events of days of future past (70s), why is the interior of the building the same as the 70s in the future. Could that have been because of wolverine changing the past?

Comment: It could be because they decided to decorate it the same. Wolverine doesn't have to have anything to do with it.